# My program keeps looping in the first do...while loop even when condition isn't met

Tags: c++, windows, loops, shared-libraries

I started learning C++ 3 days ago, and after some experimenting with loops and vector I decided to do something actually useful with it: an Account Manager.

The point is, I'm using a do...while loop, for the 1rst action in my program (which is adding a new website), however past this point, the loop won't end even when the condition isn't met any more.

I tried to debug it for a good 30 minutes and found nothing odd.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    /*Introduction
    //Ask whether the user(me) wants to open an account already created, add a new one, or remove an existing one
    To show credentials a master password is required
    I need something that can:
        1. Find the place where credentials are supposed to be filled
        2. Enter them efficiently
        3. Bonus : Submit the data on the website and automatically connect*/


    int userAction; // Variable de sélection de la première action
    string siteNameVar("site"), urlVar("url"), userNameVar("username"), passwordVar("pass") ; 
    char sureVerification;

    vector<string> siteName(0); // Vectors containing respectively : "The sites names"
    vector<string> url(0); // Vectors containing respectively : "The sites urls"
    vector<string> userName(0); // Vectors containing respectively : "The  usernames"
    vector<string> password(0); // Vectors containing respectively : "The  passwords"



    cout << "What will you do?" << endl;

    cout << "1. Add a website account" << endl
         << "2. Connect to an existing account" << endl
         << "3. Delete an account"<< endl;

    cin >> userAction; // This is where the user enter his choice

    switch (userAction){
        case 1: // Add a new element in the vectors


           do{
                //Site Name
                do{
                    cout << "Enter the site's name (or how you want to call it)" << endl;
                    cin >> siteNameVar;
                    cout << "Are you sure? 1 = yes | Anything else = no" << endl;
                    cin >> sureVerification;
                }
                while (sureVerification != 1);




                //Site's Url
                do{
                    cout << "Enter the site's login page url" << endl;
                    cin >> urlVar;
                    cout << "Are you sure? 1 = yes | Anything else = no" << endl;
                    cin >> sureVerification;
                }

                while(sureVerification != 1);
                url.push_back(urlVar);

                // Username
                do{
                    cout << "Enter your account's username" << endl;
                    cin >> userNameVar;
                    cout << "Are you sure? 1 = yes | Anything else = no" << endl;
                    cin >> sureVerification;
                }

                while(sureVerification != 1);
                userName.push_back(userNameVar);

                // Password
                do{
                    cout << "Enter your account's password" << endl;
                    cin >> passwordVar;
                    cout << "Are you sure? 1 = yes | Anything else = no" << endl;
                    cin >> sureVerification;
                }

                while(sureVerification != 1);
                password.push_back(passwordVar);

                //Display Everything

                cout << "So the site's name is :" << siteName.back() << endl 
                     << "The login page url is :" << url.back() << endl 
                     << "Your account's username is :" << userName.back() << endl 
                     << "And your password is :" << password.back() << endl;

                //Last verification
                cout << "Is everything alright? 1 = yes | Anything else = no" << endl;
                cin >> sureVerification;
            }
            while(sureVerification != 1);




            cin.get();

            break;
        case 2: // Connect to an existing account
            cout << "display map element names" << endl;
            break;

        case 3: // Delete an account
            cout << "display map element names2" <<endl;
            break;



    } // End of the choice sequence

    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Post all relevant code here directly as text.

Answer (score 0):

You should try cleaning the input buffer. Use cin.clear() and cin.ignore() before reading the user's input (eg. before cin >> sureVerification)

Comment: I thanks a lot for the quick answer.

I tried adding the cin.clear() function before (cin >> sureVerification), but the problem remains, no matter the sureVerification value, the loop won't end.

Comment: I didn't realize that sureVerification was a char. Have you tried sureVerification != "1"? You should add quotes if it's a char variable

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

Wow, after comparing an earlier version of my code to the code I posted, and substituting a piece of the old code to the new one (which "oddly" worked), I realized that the problem was all due to the fact that the value-type of sureVerification (read code to understand) was char and in the verification expression I had wrote the 1 (which was equivalent of "Yes" as an int.

Problem solved!